# Use rvest to read xml data contained in a .txt file

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I am trying to read xml data from the following link:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000275/000156761920010411/0001567619-20-010411.txt

When I use read_xml from the rvest package

```
link <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000275/000156761920010411/0001567619-20-010411.txt"
html_test <- read_xml(link)
```

I get an error:

"Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  Opening and ending tag mismatch: ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME line 3 and SEC-HEADER [76]"

Is there a way to read this text file and extract certain xml tags?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dealing with a corrupt xml file, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493728/how-to-fix-xml-opening-and-ending-tag-mismatch-error). Reading with `read_html` works. You can then put that into a list and work with that, but might not be feasible depending on what exactly you need to extract.

```
library(xml2)
link <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000275/000156761920010411/0001567619-20-010411.txt"
html_test <- read_html(link)

html_list <- as_list(html_test)
```